# Apache cannot start

Tags: windows, apache, osgeo4w

I installed the OsGeo4W-Installer and finally I want to open the link:localhost
but at present, I tried to start apache, but failed.
I checked the port 80, it was ok-

I tried to find the error by cmd, open the bin, httpd.exe, but no result.

Can anyone tell me about this error?

I use Windows 7

Comment: can you share the error message you get when starting it maybe it may help solving the problem. You can also double check if there is any application running on the same port

Answer (score 2):

`I tried to find the error by cmd, open the bin, httpd.exe,`

So when you're in the cmd window, instead of running just `httpd.exe`, what you need to do is run:

```
httpd.exe -t
```

This will check (test) the syntax of your configuration file and if you have an error it will give you a general description of the error, and importantly the line number in your configuration file where it thinks the error is...